# Best way for database connection?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Currently using `public MyDbContext() : base("<database_name>")` when debugging my application on local machine. An MDF file is created in App_Data.

Can I make it automatically choose local SQL Server 2016 instance after publish?

I usually specify `base("name=<conn_string>")` but then I have to switch connection string every time I publish.

Comment: Take a look at web.config transforms. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @SteveGreene, that is the solution. Make a post so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add to your Web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="...."/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

and use everywhere:

```
public MyDbContext() : base("MyContext")
```

In that way you need change only config file